# how to fix CORS issue for android version 9 at ionic 4

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cors

My Ioinc 4 is working at chrome and firefox browser, but cors does not wrok at android version 9. My Http Header is below.

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
```

const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
        this.loaderService.show();

```
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { 
        'Authorization': token, 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      }});
    } else {
      request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      }});
    }
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return throwError(error);
      }),
      finalize(() => { 
        this.loaderService.hide();
       }));
  }
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this https://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

You can use native http plugin for http request this handle cors automatically here is a link : `https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http`